# vertical buttons group. How to make all buttons one size?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Could you please advice how to make buttons in vertical buttons group one size ( smallest button would have the same size as a bigest one)?, ie. all buttons would have same size independent on the text inside.

```html
<div class="container body">
                    <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                        <a href="{% url "boats:boats"   %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</button></a>
                        <a href="{% url "boats:boat_edit" current_boat.pk %}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</button></a>
                        <a href="{% url "boats:boat_delete" current_boat.pk %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Delete</button></a>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify widths to both anchor tag and button tag.

```css
.btn-group-vertical a, .btn-group-vertical button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container body">
  <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</button></a>
    <a href=""> <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</button></a>
    <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Delete</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working Fine :)